# Wrong output at last Row, Sodoku puzzle

Tags: c++

I write a sodoku solver, everything seems to be fine until the last line of the output is not correct. can someone point me to the right direction why only the last line is not correct? The commented part of the array is supposed to be the correct output.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int Max = 9;
//Sodoku test problem 
int grid [Max][Max] = { {5, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                  { 6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0 },
                  { 0, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0 },
                  { 8, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3 },
                  { 4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1 },
                  { 7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6 },
                  { 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 0 },
                  { 0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 9, 0, 0, 5 },
                  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 7, 9 } };
                  //{ 3, 4, 5, 2, 8, 6, 1, 7, 9 } };


int grid2 [Max][Max];
//The printing function to print the array

void Print(int grid [Max][Max])
{
    for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
    {
        for (int j =0; j<9; j++)
        {
            cout << grid[i][j]<<" , " ;

        }
        cout <<"\n";
    }       
}


void CopyArr(int grid [Max][Max], int grid2 [Max][Max])
{
    for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
    {
        for (int j =0; j<9; j++)
        {
            grid2[i][j] = grid[i][j];

        }
        
    }       
}
```

```
bool IsValid(int y, int x, int n)
{
    for (int i=0;i <Max; i++)
    {
        if (grid[y][i] == n)
            return false;
    }
    for (int i=0;i <Max; i++)
    {
        if (grid[i][x] == n)
            return false;
    }
    int a = (x/3) * 3;
    int b = (y/3) * 3;
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            if ( grid[b+i][a+i] == n)
                return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

The function that drives the puzzle

```
void Solve()
{
    for (int y=0; y<Max; y++)
    {
        for (int x =0; x<Max; x++)
        {
            if( grid[y][x] == 0)
            {
                for (int n=1; n<10; n++)
                {
                    if (IsValid(y,x,n))
                    {
                        grid[y][x] = n;
                        Solve();
                        grid[y][x] = 0;
                    }
                
                }
                return;
            }
            
        }
    }
    CopyArr(grid, grid2);
}
```

The main function

```
int main()
{
    Solve();
    cout <<"============================ "<<endl;
    Print(grid2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your inner loop in `IsValid()` should you not refer to `j` somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ( grid[b+i][a+i] == n)
```

Shouldn't one of those `i` actually be `j`?